# Having issues installing pods

Tags: xcode

Hi i am having trouble installing pods. I thought the below problem was due to anaconda which i had installed on my mac, so i uninstalled anaconda, but it is still giving me the same issue. Im trying to install google maps and google places to my xcode app but getting the below error. any solutions would be great.

I have already reinstalled cocoapods, after deleting anaconda

thanks

Darrens-MBP:Mapit darrenjay$ open -a Xcode Podfile
Darrens-MBP:Mapit darrenjay$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing GoogleMaps (3.0.3)

[!] Error installing GoogleMaps
[!] /anaconda3/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/fg/jlp2pz7d36b2p_xfjktklkq40000gn/T/d20190312-1965-1q1vmof/file.tgz https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/4fb8b2192f32cf7c/GoogleMaps-3.0.3.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found

Comment: its now resolved after a clean install of my mac operating system. extreme i know but i was stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**its now resolved after a clean install of my mac operating system. extreme i know but i was stuck**